# Kubernetes only open services when all the deployments are ready

Tags: kubernetes

When I'm redeploying my Kubernetes services I'm finding downtime most of the time. I have set up the `livenessProbe` and the `readinessProbe`, but when the old deployment is changed by the new one, I'm having 502/503 errors when trying to access my server.

In those moments, I can see that the new pods are not ready yet, while the old ones are still ready. However, it looks like the network traffic is being redirected in a wrong way.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing here? How can I delay the new service to be ready (like using `minReadySeconds` in a deployment, maybe?)

What's the best way to monitor this issue and find a solution?

Comment: You can add a delay to the probes, but it sounds like an issue with your app reporting that its healthy before it really is

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app is reporting that it's ready when in reality it is not.

First check how your readiness works and see based on what information the application decides that it's ready and change it if necessary.

Answering your other question:

> How can I delay the new service to be ready?

You can use [startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes) or `initialDelaySeconds` for [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes).

Which one you use depends on the application and how you define probes.